# Change top menu color in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

Good day, i'm having difficulties changing wordpress top navigation menu.

**Here's the full css path :**

[Css image path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PWyLb.png)

**I have tried to apply this css code**

```
.secondary-navigation .menu-top-menu-container .menu pp menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73 {
      color: blue;
}
```

But it has no effect :(

Can someone point out what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please share some code or url ? So someone has quickly fixed your issue.

Comment: Please add a website link. You want to change the menu text color?

Comment: @jaydeeppatel Sharing links is against SO rules.

Comment: @David.J Sharing links is against SO rules.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know what is the result is. thanks.

```
.secondary-navigation .menu-top-menu-container .menu-item {
   color: blue;
}
```

or

```
.secondary-navigation .menu-top-menu-container .menu-item a {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: @Kristjan Tampere, Check my answer above and let me know if there is any issue.

Comment: @Kristjan Tampere, It's my pleasure. Please mark this answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can target directly it's first immediate parent and then the class itself, like this:

```
#menu-top-menu li {
   color: blue;
}
```

Comment: try this #menu-top-manu li a { color: blue; } Your html code provided is incomplete

Answer (score 0):

So the issue you are having is you are

1) calling multiple classes on the same element incorrectly. in the html the classes need to be separated by a space but in the css this is not the case.

so these classes here =

```
pp menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-73
```

should be written as [in your CSS file] =

```
.pp.menu-item menu-item-type-post_type.menu-item-object-page.menu-item-73
```

[also you missed out the . in front of each class!]

2) HOWEVER, you do not need to include every class on the element to select it. All you really need is just a single class.

so you could use =

```
.secondary-navigation .menu-top-menu-container .menu-item {color: blue;}
```

which i believe someone else has already mentioned.

calling an html element by using mulitple elements can be useful if the circumstance is right [like needing to target some more specifically], but in your case you will be fine with the above!